# Is it good to use Python garbage collecter inside the program?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I have written an NLP GUI program with python. Everything works well and there is no problem. Since the program should process large corpus and make graphs, in order to free memory and let the processes to fit inside the RAM, i have used `gc.collect()` in several parts to delete some big variables.
My question is this: is it right and efficient to use `gc.collect()` manually in several parts when processing big datasets or let the python use its automatic garbage collector?? I mean, does it have a bad effect on the flow of the program or `gc.collect()` works well? I have heard that using `gc.collect()` when processing big datasets, have bad effects on the program flow and even some times it wastes more RAM space to delete and free variables. I really appreciate answers which guide me.

Comment: Python automatically does garbage collection, though you can use garbage collection in your program but it is not recommended apart from some certain case scenarios.

Comment: @geek Thanks for your reply. You mean it is better to not manually use garbage collector and let the python automatically collect them? Because I am not sure that python does a collect before entering the part of the program that uses the most RAM space, I have put ```gc.collect()``` manually. If you advise, I let the python automatically collects them

Comment: A case scenario where it it applicable is: A Python Program that declare a significant number of objects in a loop running > 100,000  times it's may be justifiable to use gc.collect() to free up memory space of already declared objects

Comment: @geek The thing that matters in my case is the size of the variable created before entering to the main part of the code which again produces a large variable. Suppose that the part  ```A``` of the program produces variables about 2 GB and part ```B``` uses some of them and produces a large variable about 2.5 GB. To free the space of the program, after finishing part  ```B``` and before entering part  ```C``` I have put ```gc.collect```. Do you think it is efficient to delete manually variables of size 2GB by  ```gc.collect``` or let the program automatically do this?

Comment: I'd not expect this to do anything, unless your code creates a large number of circular dependencies. See the duplicate. You'd be better of using a memory profiler (such as [memray](https://github.com/bloomberg/memray)) and see if you can free memory by clearing variables you no longer need.

Comment: Deleting python variable merely deletes the variable but the object is still referenced in memory. python garbage collector does automatically freeing old referenced objects. When you are consider using gc.collect() u need to be sure of the main problem with your program which could be anything.